# Families of Riccati Equations for a closed subspace?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

Let $N$ be a positive integer, fix constants $a_i,b_{i,j},c_{k,i},d_{k,i,j}\in \mathbb{R}$, 
and let $X$ be the subspace of all $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R}^d)$ satisfying:

- $f=f_0e_0+\sum_{i=1}^N f_i e_i$ for some $f_i \in C^2(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$,
- There exists $c_0,\dots,c_N\in \mathbb{R}$ for which $f$ is a solution to the matrix differential Riccati equation:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  \partial_x f_0 & = c_0+\sum_{i=1}^N a_i f_i(x) - \frac1{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^N b_{i,j}f_i(x)f_j(x); \qquad &f_0(0)=0
  \\
  \partial_x f_k & = c_k +\sum_{i=1}^N c_{k,i} f_i(x) - \frac1{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^N d_{k,i,j}f_i(x)f_j(x) ; \qquad &f_k(0)=0.
  \end{aligned}
  $$

Then, is the subspace $X$ closed in $C^2(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$.

Note: *Here $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors on $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$.*

Comment: The space $X$ is "the subspace of $C^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ consisting of all functions satisfying": what functions, what property? Do you mean *all function **f** satisfying ...* ? Or all $f_0$? Also, as it is defined $f$ is a combination of the $e_i$, thus a vector valued function, but maybe there should be $f_0e_0$ instead of $f_0$?

Comment: Indeed it is vector-valued; and satisfies the two properties.  I have added clarifications.  Thank you for pointing this out Pietro.

Comment: I don't really see where the dimension $d$ is relevant. Basically you are looking at $F = (f_0, \ldots, f_N)$ solving the equation $F' = C + A F + B (F\otimes F)$, where the matrix $A$ has vanishing first column, and the rank 3 tensor $B$ satisfies $B_{k0j} = B_{kj0} = 0$. Your $f$ is then just a projection of $F$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Also, it is kind of weird to call $X$ a subspace: the Riccati equation is nonlinear, and the solution set should not be a linear subspace. Do you mean subspace in the sense of a topological subspace and closed just meaning in terms of the $C^2$ topology?

Comment: Note that you can differentiate another time and write an equivalent second order system,  where $c=(c_0,\dots,c_N)$ now appears as initial data: $$\cases{ f''(x)=G(f,f')\\f(0) =0\\f'(0) =c}$$
Clearly the set $X$ of all solutions $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^{N+1})$ of  $$\cases{ f''(x)=G(f,f')\\f(0) =0 }$$
with free $f'(0)$ is closed in $C^2$ (=wrto uniform convergence on compact set with first and second derivatives): if a sequence of solutions converges to $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^{N+1})$, then everything passes to the limit, included the initial data, and $f\in X$.

Comment: Maybe you had a different question in mind?

Comment: No this is the correct question.  However, I'm having having trouble understanding how the last step is obvious.

Comment: If you agree that your $X$ is the set of $f\in C^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^{N+1})$ solving $f''=G(f,f')$ with$f(0)=0$, for some polynomial map $G$, then $X$ is closed in $C^2$ just because $G$ is continuous.

Comment: Actually this is clear now... Thanks Pietro.  I will happily accept the comments if you record them into an answer.